# Trying to click a date-field on days-grid

Tags: vba, selenium, wai-aria

I'm trying to click an element on a days-grid of the calendar-slider

[image: source]

I am able to find the element by looping the `xpath` but can't click it as "ElementNotVisibleError" / "element not interactable"

```
For i = 1 To 42
    If obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[" & i & "]").Attribute("data-ctx-id") = loadingdate Then
        obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li[" & i & "]").Click
        GoTo got_it_1
    End If
Next i
```

any hint?

add: link to source: [google](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zWi292XfImfSs3XTrQld_iRnUqEP6yCUvzQscc8F1gY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you paste that HTML in text format here?

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: added - 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zWi292XfImfSs3XTrQld_iRnUqEP6yCUvzQscc8F1gY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The question title can be re-framed to be more generic

Answer (score 0):

maybe the element you're seeking is not visible yet. selenium can't click the element if it isn't visible

Comment: at least i can see it with my eyes while chrome is excecuting - would "wait" help?

Comment: add: also with "wait" i get "runtimeerror 11"